# Junit 5 test failing when running togheter

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5

Ok, so this test work individually fine, but for some reason, they fail when running together, as you can see, I real a String of values from a File.

When running together, it looks like the app stops reading the commands of the file after a few entries.

Any ideas?

One example of the file text:
10
10
5
5
e
3
3
3
1
5

at the second 3 of the sequence, the app stops reading the values.

All this test work individually.

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_METHOD)
public class MarsRoverTest {

   @BeforeEach
   public void setUp() {
       cleanUpMars();
   }

   //Test rover's movement
   @Test
   public void roverSetUp_OK() throws OutOfMarsException {
       System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(getInstructions(ROVER_SET_UP_OK)));

       MarsRover.main(new String[]{});
       assertEquals(RIGHT, Mars.getInstance().getMars()[5][5]);
   }

   @Test()
   public void roverSetUp_OutOfMars() {
       System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(getInstructions(ROVER_SET_UP_ERROR)));

       OutOfMarsException exception = assertThrows(OutOfMarsException.class, () ->
               MarsRover.main(new String[]{}));
       assertEquals("You set the Rover in the Space!", exception.getMessage());
   }

   @Test
   public void roverMoveAround_OK() throws OutOfMarsException {
       System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(getInstructions(ROVER_MOVE_AROUND_OK)));

       MarsRover.main(new String[]{});

       assertEquals(RIGHT, Mars.getInstance().getMars()[5][0]);
   }


   //Test rover's rotation
   @Test
   public void roverRotateUp_OK() throws OutOfMarsException {
       System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(getInstructions(ROVER_ROTATE_UP_OK)));

       MarsRover.main(new String[]{});
       assertEquals(UP, Mars.getInstance().getMars()[4][5]);
   }


   //Test rover's rotation
   @Test
   public void roverRotateLeft_OK() throws OutOfMarsException {
       System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(getInstructions(ROVER_ROTATE_LEFT_OK)));

       MarsRover.main(new String[]{});
       assertEquals(LEFT, Mars.getInstance().getMars()[5][4]);
   }


   //Test rover's rotation
   @Test
   public void roverRotateDown_OK() throws OutOfMarsException {
       System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(getInstructions(ROVER_ROTATE_DOWN_OK)));

       MarsRover.main(new String[]{});
       assertEquals(DOWN, Mars.getInstance().getMars()[6][5]);
   }


   private byte[] getInstructions(String path) {
       try {
           return Files.readString(Path.of(path)).getBytes();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
   }

   private void cleanUpMars() {
       Mars.getInstance().setMarsReady(true);
   }
```

Mars is a Singleton instance

```
public class Mars {

   private static Mars INSTANCE;

   private int sizeX;

   private int sizeY;

   private String[][] mars; //Map of Mars
   private boolean marsReady = false; //I hade to add this for the testing, needs improvement
   private Mars(){

   }

   public static Mars getInstance() {
       if(INSTANCE == null) {
           INSTANCE = new Mars();
       }
       return INSTANCE;
   }
```

Mars class is this:

```
package org.mars.entities;

import static org.mars.constants.MarsConstants.OBSTACLE;
import static org.mars.utils.ReaderUtils.requestInt;

/**
 * Singleton class
 */
public class Mars {

    private static Mars INSTANCE;

    private int sizeX;

    private int sizeY;

    private String[][] mars; //Map of Mars
    private boolean marsReady = false; //I hade to add this for the testing, needs improvement
    private Mars(){

    }

    public static Mars getInstance() {
        if(INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new Mars();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static void removeInstance() {
        INSTANCE = null;
    }

    public int getSizeX() {
        return sizeX;
    }

    public void setSizeX(int sizeX) {
        this.sizeX = sizeX;
    }

    public int getSizeY() {
        return sizeY;
    }

    public void setSizeY(int sizeY) {
        this.sizeY = sizeY;
    }

    public String[][] getMars() {
        return mars;
    }

    public void setMars(String[][] mars) {
        this.mars = mars;
    }

    public boolean isMarsReady() {
        return marsReady;
    }

    public void setMarsReady(boolean marsReady) {
        this.marsReady = marsReady;
    }

    /**
     * Define the size of the map for the rover
     */
    public static void setMarsSize() {
        System.out.println("Insert horizontal map size:");
        getInstance().sizeX = requestInt();
        System.out.println("Insert vertical map size:");
        getInstance().sizeY = requestInt();

        getInstance().mars = new String[INSTANCE.sizeX][INSTANCE.sizeY];

        if(!getInstance().isMarsReady())
            addObstacles();
    }

    /**
     * Shows the map of Mars with the rover and obstacles
     */
    public static void printMars(){
        for (String[] placeX: INSTANCE.mars) {

            System.out.print("|");

            for (String placeY: placeX) {

                if(placeY != null && !placeY.isBlank())
                    System.out.print("_" + placeY + "_");
                else System.out.print("___");

                System.out.print("|");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add obstacles for the mars Map
     */
    private static void addObstacles() {
        int min = 0;
        int numberOfObstacles = (int)(Math.random() * getInstance().sizeX * getInstance().sizeY / 10) + min;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObstacles; i++) {
            int randomX = (int)(Math.random() * getInstance().sizeX -1) + min;
            int randomY = (int)(Math.random() * getInstance().sizeY -1) + min;

            getInstance().mars[randomX][randomY] = OBSTACLE;
        }
    }
}
```

And the main app:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws OutOfMarsException {

        try {
            reader = new Scanner(System.in);

            //Map size configured
            setMarsSize();
            //Rover initial position
            roverCar.setRoverPosition();
            //Show mars map
            printMars();
```

Comment: Without the code of Mars, it's hard to tell. It's pretty sure you don't reinitialise your code properly.

Comment: @XavierBouclet Yes, that's what I think too, but I try it in different weys and I could not solve it, Mars is a Singleton class and MarsRover is just the typical main app

Comment: Could you add the error you get and the MarsRover code?

Comment: Your asserts are going against the `String[][] mars`. I would expect that this array must be re-initialized.
Generally, a stateful singleton is not a good idea.

Comment: @Timo  I updated the question adding the code of MArs and part of the Main app

Comment: @XavierBouclet The error is the test failing, is not an error itself, is that the position of the rover is not on the place it should be

Comment: `System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(getInstructions(ROVER_ROTATE_LEFT_OK)));` - you are breaking a lot of things due to poor design, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73108962/how-to-process-files-for-unit-testing/73109083#73109083