# How to process files for unit testing?

Tags: java

I have 5 input files in a folder, for each input file (1.in for example), I process it and produce a new output file (1.out) printing a integer in it.

How do I do this?

Right now this is what I have, I want to run different files like a2.in and print output in new file like a2.out (name them based on the input file names).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("a1.in"));
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("a1.out")));

public int compareTo(Event a) {
            return ans;
}
```

Comment: Pass the filename as an argument to `main`.

Comment: The following should also work: `PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("a1.out");`

Answer (score 2):

That depends on unit test and assertion library you are using, below is example for `junit-jupiter` akin `junit5` and `assertJ`:

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource(delimiterString = ";", value = {"a1.in;a1.out", "a2.in;a2.out""})
void test(String input, String output) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (InputStream in = getStream(input); InputStream expected = getStream(output)) {
        // test body reading from in and writing to baos
        assertThat(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()))
                .hasSameContentAs(expected);
    }
}

InputStream getStream(String resource) {
    return getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + resource);
}
```

UPD (Thanks [Reinier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/768644/rzwitserloot) for comments).

If your goal is to test `#main` method (i.e. you are writing CLI application, which reads and writes some files) and your `#main` method looks like:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(args[2])));
    // do something with br and pw
}
```

consider redesigning it to something like:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    main(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(args[0])), Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(args[1])));
}

public static void main(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    try (
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out);
    ) {
        // do something with br and pw
        pw.flush();
    }
}
```

in that case the testability of `#main` method gets improved.

Comment: I think this is a few ballparks beyond where OP is. In particular, OP wants to _write a test file out_ during their unit test. Which is bizarre and doesn't fit this model at all (which goes with getResourceAsStream which doesn't allow writing). Upvoted because this is where OP needs to end up, but it needs more context.